# nested (div) acting up

Tags: css, html

I know the solution is very simple, but I have come here for help to get the answer quickly I hope. So I have my page set up with Divs and I have a "content" div and with in that content div I have a **contentarea** div, so here is the problem I have run into: I want to position the "**contentarea**" div in the content div, the "contentarea" div will be centered in the content div with a little margin on the top and bottom.  The problem is when I set the margin "top" for the contentarea div the the "contentarea div" is not actually moving but the content div itself is moving, and creating white space between the menu. Some how the contentarea div when moved, moves the content div. Any solutions? I want the content div to stay where it is when I position my content area div!!

Comment: could we see some code?

Answer (score 0):

For the main div use:

```
overflow: auto;
```

Or overflow visible :). U can also set padding on the main div :).
Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use overflow, you can do the trick with padding, look at this code :

Exemple :

> ```
> .contentdiv {
>     padding-top: 10px;
> }
>
> Or
>
> .container {
>     padding-top: 10px;
> }
> ```

The full exemple : http://jsfiddle.net/Ca4K2/